# How to autocomplete user's restaurant search using Google API

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, xmlhttprequest, google-places-api

I have a working Google Autocomplete search, but I would only like to limit the results to that of type "restaurant". Currently, there are only options to limit the place "type" to "geocode", "address", "establishment", "(regions)", or "(cities)", but I would like to further limit the results to only include restaurants.

For example:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Chi&types=**(restaurants)**&location=latitude,longitude&radius=50000&key=YOUR_KEY_HERE

Should autocomplete to restaurants that start with "Chi" near the given location.

Comment: Did you post the feature request in public issue tracker? https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:PlacesAPI%20type:Enhancement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) will then favor locations within those boundaries. Note, however, that since this isn't a hard boundary, if there are matches for the search outside the boundaries it will return those.

Take note that the Places service is a self-contained library, separate from the main [Maps API JavaScript code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) use the functionality contained within this library, you must first load it using the libraries parameter in the Maps API bootstrap URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

In addition to providing a list of places within an area, the Places service can also return detailed information about a specific place. Once a place has been returned in a place search response, its place ID can be used to request additional details about that place, such as its complete address, phone number, user rating and reviews, etc.

```
function initialize() {

var options = {
types: ['(cities)'],
componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
};

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

For the Place Search, you can include the `type` parameter to restrict s the results to places matching the specified type. See the list of supported types here: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1

Comment: `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` only supports following 
 types: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3

Comment: @Rashomon any alternate solution to achieve this?